# ¿Qué método uso para ordenar alfabeticamente por nombre un objeto ordenado?

Tags: javascript, html, ordenamiento

Tengo una clase con una lista de datos.
Dicha lista tiene las propiedades: datos,modo,monto,comentarios.
Necesito ordenar mi lista alfabéticamente creciente en funcion de la propiedad "datos", la cual tiene formato String de la form "nombre(direccion, telefono)".
Cree el siguiente método pero no me lo ordena bien:

```
ordenNombreDonanteCreciente() {
        this.listaDatos.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a.nombre - b.nombre);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta con más detalles técnicos acerca de tu problema de la manera más explícita posible, esto aumentará las posibilidades de recibir una buena respuesta por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola en la documentación hay un ejemplo que puedes usar, pero también te explica ciertas cosas que debes tener en cuenta, te la dejo [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), y te escribo un ejemplo.

```
var items = [
    { name: 'idward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'ndward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'Idward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
    { name: 'And', value: 45 },
    { name: 'The', value: -12 },
    { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
    { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    }
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
});


console.log({ items })
```